# Telecentric lens references, working distance formula

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, lenses, imaging

I would like to learn about telecentric lenses for use in an experiment. So far, I have found scant resources (mostly optical companies) and I understand the basic principal of a simple telecentric setup from the figures therein.

However, one thing that I definitely do not understand is the working distance of a telecentric lens. One of the tutorials has stated that one encounters distortion when an object is imaged outside of the working distance... However, I have no idea how to calculate this distance so that something can be designed for my own setup.

Comment: working distance is simply the distance between the focal plane and the nearest optical surface. If you know where your focal plane is you should be able to read this off your drawing for the design.

Comment: So, with this in mind, I know my working distance... However, I would like to know how to calculate the range over which a given lens setup will remain approximately telecentric (to within 1%, say). 
Some sort of idea for how to build a telecentric setup would be amazing as well, but my University's library has got nothing on the subject, and I have had little luck searching on the web.